# Spring annotation @Order

Tags: spring-boot, spring-annotations

spring boot annotation @order

`The lower the number, the higher the precedence`

If I use `@Order(-1000)`, what's that means? extremely high ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, `@Order(-1000)` will give you a higher precedence than say `@Order(-1)` or `@Order(1000)`.

`@Order(-2147483648)` has the highest precedence.

See more here https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/constant-values.html#org.springframework.core.Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE